# Is this Homebrew Fault Feature Balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, homebrew-review

Long story short, I've fiddled with character creation in DnD for a good while before I actually started playing, and I really love the idea of starting with a handicap. I made a character who has the following homebrew Fault in conjunction with my DM, but it functions as a Feature:

> Narcolepsy.
> Whenever you roll for initiative, roll a 1d4. On a 2-4, you succeed and stay awake. On a 1, you fall asleep, and are affected by unconsciousness rules. Whenever you are charmed or frightened, you instead fall unconscious.

Is this balanced for standard DnD adventures?

Comment: Balanced *in comparison to what*? A baseline character without this fault? You've only described disadvantageous things, what benefit are you trying to balance this against?

Comment: Valid. No such thing as balancing if there's nothing to balance but negatives.

Comment: I've edited to replace "balanced" with "fun", since (as discussed in comments above) the term "balanced" isn't meaningful here.

Comment: I've rolled this back. Asking "is this fun" is opinion based.

Comment: Rolled back again. “Too much” is subjective just like someone trying to define someone else’s fun.

Comment: @NautArch-is-skeptical-about-SE Fair.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### This is pretty bad for your character

Falling unconscious is pretty bad.  It means that you miss your first action in combat, and probably one of your allies has to miss their first action in combat as well to wake you up.

Most DMs will have the monsters ignore unconscious targets, but if your DM isn't feeling nice, monsters can attack you with advantage and their attacks against you are automatically critical hits.

There might be some circumstances (climbing or swimming) where falling unconscious would simply kill you.

### This is probably bad roleplaying

In a "standard D&D adventure", the player characters are competent and skilled -- they're heroic adventurers trying to thwart evil and save the town.

The character you've described doesn't sound competent and skilled.  They sound like someone with a crippling disability, someone who should stay far away from danger and definitely never go into a dungeon.

Imagine a group of four competent, skilled player characters.  Why would they want to bring your character with them?  Wouldn't they say: "no, this adventure isn't safe for you, you should stay home, we'll bring somebody else instead"?

### Talk to your fellow players

You've written: "I really love the idea of starting with a handicap."

Do your fellow players also love the idea of you starting with a handicap?  Are they going to have handicaps too?

You've asked about a "standard D&D adventure", which is played as a  *cooperative* game, meaning that the players (and the characters) are working together to beat the monsters.

If your fellow players are trying to play D&D as a cooperative game, then they might feel unhappy that you're, in some sense, "not trying to win".  They might feel resentful that they have to take time away from doing the things they like (fighting monsters together) to take care of your character -- especially when your character's problem is something you invented for yourself, because you wanted the rest of the group to have to take care of you.

Comment: It is worth noting that Unconscious is easier to end (one Action to shake awake) than Charmed and Frightened.

Comment: @ValhallaGH Although the other 2 conditions don’t stop you from participating nor take a compatriot out to wake you up.

Answer (score 6):

#### 25% of the time, I am a tremendous liability.

This is what this "feature" is. 25% of the time we enter combat, you fall unconscious, and not only do you not contribute, you become a tremendous liability as you are now extremely vulnerable. I would let you die at the first opportunity, with the hope that you would reroll a new character without this trait, because playing with this character at the table sounds terrible.

This is not balanced, it is a wildly detrimental trait.

Comment: Edited according to your comment. Please edit your post correspondingly.

Answer (score 2):

#### 25% of the time, encounters will be unbalanced.

The standard DMG encounter method is to total monster XP and have it match the XP Thresholds by Character Level table in the DMG.  What your fault means is that 25% of the time, your character won't count towards your party's contribution to the encounter.  So the difficulty of the encounter will be higher than expected for the party.  The effect will be greater the smaller your party is.

**Your table of players has to answer if they consider this fun.**

Answer (score 1):

### Impossible to tell without knowing what it’s supposed to be balanced *against* but assessing it purely in isolation - no, it’s not balanced

The problem here is that a question “is X balanced” is that it’s pretty meaningless without knowing what it’s supposed to be balanced against. A lot of the time people just use mental shortcuts if something is obvious - as an example, a question of the type “Is my homebrew race X balanced?” is **really** asking “Is it balanced *against the official races in the sourcebooks*?”, that last part is just implied.

Here you seem to be making quite big changes to the way character creation rules work and you can’t just do something like this on the fly, you really need to think it through - is every character starting with a Fault Feature, is one mandatory or optional? If it’s optional, do they get a benefit of some sort too? Do players get to choose one themselves or roll one? Can you give some examples of other Fault Features? You see where I’m going with this, right? Flesh this out, write out exactly how your rules on the Fault Features work, then it will be possible to tell whether this particular one is balanced. It’s an interesting concept you got there but it needs more work.

If on the other hand you mean just adding this onto a PC’s sheet, as-is, without doing anything else to this same PC or the rest of them, then no, this is very unbalanced, it’s a pure drawback, and a quite severe one. Roughly 1 combat in every 4 you will begin unconscious and falling unconscious instead of merely being frightened or charmed is much worse either (consider for example among other rules for unconsciousness that any hit is a critical hit by default, so prepare for taking a lot of very high damage). This is inherently imbalanced since it has you suffer a detriment but doesn’t even it out with anything positive.

Since you mention wanting to be balanced for “standard d&d adventures”, a way to use it that I could envisage would be as a sort of counterbalance to a character build that’s already massively overpowered.

As a side note that isn’t really about balance, this is going to be not very enjoyable for you to play and, depending on the table and campaign, could *really* annoy your party members.

Answer (score 0):

### This is unbalanced and may be unfun for the others

**This is unbalanced**. It's only downside, and an extremely harsh downside at that. For an average party of four, it will take out 1/4 of their firepower, which in a balanced deadly encounter, where someone might die if the party is full, now suddenly you'll have a severe risk someone will die. And with an unconscious character lying around, fleeing as an option is hampered big time.

**You should check if this is unfun for the other players**. Fun is a matter of taste of course, and maybe all your fellow players told you they are OK with this. But if you did not not check with them, you should, lest you get your fun of playing your handicapped character *at their cost*. This is not just between you and DM, it is between you and all other players. They are the ones that have to make up for your self-imposed shortcomings, and unless they signed up for that, chances are they'll not be pleased.

To share from my own experience, my Wizard sometimes preps suboptimal spells like *gust of wind* for fun, and I get a lot of flak for it from the others, when I don't have a staple like *invisibility* because of it. They hate that I indulge exploring weaker options like that. Its not fun *for them*, so I keep it low level. This here is *way* worse as a liability.

#### Other options

If you are looking to play a character with heavy liabilities, D&D which is mostly heroic fantasy may not be the best system for you. Try *Call of Cthulhu* instead. There, being blind or narcoleptic might even have some value for survivability.

Comment: One persons fun may or may not be someone else’s.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i wouldnt expect any less.

Comment: I neither upvoted nor downvoted as I feel most of the answer is just berating the OP for *possibly* annoying their teammates, there’s lots of different groups, your experience is not everyone else’s experience, seems like you’re in a group of heavy optimisers, my table as a counter example is nothing like that at all. Meanwhile, the thing they actually asked for, whether it’s balanced, takes only 1 short paragraph

Comment: @AnnaAG I think you are right. I adjusted that section.

Comment: @NautArch-is-skeptical-about-SE Upon further reflection, also based on Anna's comment which helped me consider, I changed my answer to allow for other perspectives of fun.